# Arithmetic operation on sequence on integers

Tags: algorithm

I have N integers numbers: 1,2,3...N

The task is to use +,-,*,/ to make expression 0.

For example -1*2+3+4-5=0

How can I do it?

May be some code on C/C++ ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It's actually programming because I've found it in my problem set of university course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If N % 4 == 0, for every four consecutive integers a, b, c, d, take a - b - c + d

If N % 4 == 1, use 1 * 2 to start, then proceed as before. (i.e., 1*2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 - 8 - 8 + 9 ...)

If N % 4 == 2, start with 1 - 2 + 3 * 4 - 5 - 6, then proceed as in the N % 4 == 0 example.

If N % 4 == 3, start with 1 + 2 - 3, then proceed as in the N%4 == 0 example.

All of these find a way to get zero out of the first few integers, leaving a multiple of four integers to work on, then take advantage of the fact that the pattern a - b - c + d = 0 for any four consecutive integers.

Comment: Thanks for this simple explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), or do you know that the numbers are a sequence (e.g. 2 1 8 is forbidden). What about negative numbers?

If the sequence is not too large, i would recommend to simply bootforce it. A greedy solution would be to reduce the problem by finding subsets which can be evaluated to zero.

Comment: Thanks for article on wikipedia, that was really useful !